# How do I remove and reinstall baseboards nailed on steel framing?

Tags: drywall, baseboard, nails, skirting, board

I need help with removing skirting boards. I have no problem pulling it off and no damage wall when pulling off from timber framing, but this is the first job that I came across that skirting board was nailed through steel framing with annular ring nail.

I already pulled one side off but it did a lot of damage.

Can I do this without damaging the skirting boards?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. 1) please note that this site is for _Home_ Improvement - if this is a commercial job, technically it's off-topic. 2) Please [edit] your question to include some pictures of what your framing is like - it seems unusual to _nail_ something to _steel_ studs. 3) Annular (or ring-shank in the US) nails just don't tend to pull out cleanly, and there may not be anything you can do to salvage the trim. If you need to remove it, you may just have to accept that you'll have to replace it with new.

Comment: Yes, photos, please, or at least a better description. Wood size and species, nailing pattern, nail size and type (head style, soft or hardened), wall covering....

Comment: Can you provide a pic of the nail from the side you demo’d?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what type/ style base/ skirting board you have, but this method works on most all for me.

You will need 2 putty knives with stiff blades (about 3 or 4 inches wide), a hammer, razor knife, prybar, a pair of pliers and wood block about 12 inches long ( 30 cm).

First, cut the caulking across the top of the board with a razor knife.
Hold the knife at approximately a 45° angle to the wall. Also cut the caulking at any inside and outside corners. (Obviously this is not needed if the boards are not caulked.)

Start at an end, tap the putty knife between the wall and the board. Get it down below the top of the board at least 2 inches and pull away from the wall.

Put the 2nd putty knife in the gap and pull out to get a bigger gap. This will let you put the pry bar between the wall and the board and pull with more force. (You may find caulking that needs more cutting.)

The idea now is to find the nails and use the putty knife to shear the nails. Get the putty knife on the body of the nail and tap down using what force is needed to bend the nail. Sometimes they will break, most time they pull through the board, or out of the framing. ( either will work to get the board off.)

Occasionally you might need to pry against the wall board. If so the wood is used to pry against so not to mar the wall.

Once the board is off, use the pliers to pull any nails through the board from the backside. This leaves only a small hole in the front, sometimes no marks at all.

Good Luck.

Comment: (Also, if you do the prying at a location where there's a stud, there's less likelihood of breaking the drywall by accident.)  But I'm not understanding why you need to shear nails, or how a putty knife can do that.

Comment: Prying by the studs is great, if you can find them.  A stiff putty knife's blade will shear or bend the thin trim nails usually used to attach framing.  Since the OP said the framing is steel, the nails are probably harder and mor likely to break than bend,  But either will accomplish the task.

Comment: But why bother shearing the nails off at all?  Why not just pull them out with the baseboard?

Comment: Because they may NOT come out. Please read the question entirely.

Comment: No effing way will a putty knife shear or bend ring-shank nails in steel. We're not talking about 18 ga. trim nails here.

Comment: You all are quick to criticize this answer...but where is yours?

Comment: I'm waiting for critical details. Any answers at this point are wildly speculative. I've also voted to close for lack of detail.

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer for the same lack of question detail. It may prove to be good if my basic and reasonable assumptions are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If it is steel framing you are working with, in all my days I have only used "trim head" screws. They hold really well in metal framing and will be difficult to pull unless removed first. You can find them with a rare earth magnet on a string. Get it close it will zip onto it the rest of the way. Then you need to dig out the putty and see what type of driver it needs to remove it. It will either be a #1 square drive, #1 phillips and if it is relatively new, a #10 torx. Then again, wood butchers may have installed it (my humble opinion only) and used finish nails only driven in at angles to use as grippers in the drywall only, using the caulk, if any at the top to hold it in. Some installers may add caulk on the back to hold it as well. This could give you trouble. THAT will pull chunks off  when removing the skirting. If it is none there it will pull real easy.